# Unary Predicate results in error "called object type 'bool' is not a function or function pointer" in remove_if

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to use remove_if from the STL, and the predicate of remove_if requires a Unary Predicate. I hope to get the result of removing elements from the vector that equals "whereValue." So I'm trying to call my predicate in:

```
// Create EqualTemplate object

EqualTemplate equalTemplate = EqualTemplate(whereValueEntry, whereColIndex);


tables[tableName].table[tables[tableName].colNames[whereColName]].erase(
                    remove_if(tables[tableName].table[tables[tableName].colNames[whereColName]].begin(),
                        tables[tableName].table[tables[tableName].colNames[whereColName]].end(),
                        equalTemplate(tables[tableName].table[tables[tableName].colNames[whereColName]])), tables[tableName].table[tables[tableName].colNames[whereColName]].end());
```

My predicate is in a class called EqualTemplate:

```
// unary predicate class for use with remove_if
class EqualTemplate
{
private:
    TableEntry whereValue;
    int columnIndex;
public:
    EqualTemplate(TableEntry &value, int &columnIndexIn) : whereValue(value), columnIndex(columnIndexIn) {}
    bool operator()(vector<TableEntry>const &inputVector) { return inputVector[(uint32_t) columnIndex] == whereValue; }
};
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/remove_if.h:37:18: error: called object type 'bool' is not a function or function pointer
            if (!__pred(*__i))
```

I'm confused because the bool operator() returns a bool, which is a function. Should I be writing the code differently? Thanks!

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: You should pass the functor itself, not the result to a call of the functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite clear. You are passing a bool as `UnaryPredicate` instead of a function - this is because you are calling the function and passing its return type, a boolean, to `UnaryPredicate`. Just pass `equalTemplate`, not `equalTemplate(tables[tableName].table[tables[tableName].colNames[whereColName]])` - `std::remove_if` will call it for you.